# Javascript element.style.opacity is undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, element, setinterval, opacity

I am trying to make a JS function that flickers an element. I use a `setInterval()` for timing, but it gives the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined`.

When I try to modify the opacity not with a timer, but "by hand", that works...

What am I doing wrong?

**Usage:**

```
document.getElementById('idOfTheElement').startFlicker();
```

**The function:**

```
Element.prototype.startFlicker = function() {
    var blinkInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (parseInt(this.style.opacity) === 0) {
            this.style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
            this.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    }, 50);
};
```

Comment: Your `this` is not what you think it is. It  is out of scope inside the interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Element.prototype.startFlicker = function() {
    var self = this;

    var blinkInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (parseInt(self.style.opacity) === 0) {
            self.style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
            self.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    }, 50);
};
```

In `setInterval` `this` refers to `window`, you need store context (`this` - current element) in variable and use in `setInterval`

Answer (score 1):

Because of the context. `this.style` inside the `setInterval` refers to the global `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a reference to the element itself, because inside the setInterval function, the window object is passed as `this`.

Instead, you should give `.bind()` a try. So `this` will be a reference to the argument of the method.

```
Element.prototype.startFlicker = function() {
    var blinkInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (parseInt(this.style.opacity) === 0) {
            this.style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
            this.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    }.bind(this), 50);
};
```